# Move files from one storage account to another storage account in different tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage

I am looking to move the files from one storage account (from Tenant A) to another storage account (to Tenant B) on the same Azure account.

I have bill exports on Tenant B storage account which I have to move them to storage account on Tenant A.

How can I make a start on this problem?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

- AFAIK if the storage accounts are under different tenants, then you
  need to manually move your data.

  i.e.; When your tenants of source and destination  are not  same, you
  may need to contact ***[support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request#create-a-support-request)*** with a  support request to move the resources to a new
  tenant.
- You can use server side copy to [copy blobs between storage accounts
  in different regions and subscriptions](https://github.com/azureautomation/copying-blobs-between-storage-accounts-in-different-regions) &
- To move resources across  resource groups or subscriptions you can
  check this guide on how to: [Move resources to a new subscription or
  resource group-ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription)  or [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json) between storage accounts .